# LINQ join and Split to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to join the two tables like this

```
tableA.code.Split('-').FirstOrDefault() equals tableB.SiteCode
```

This is my query.

```
var quer = from i in tableB
           join s in tableA on i.Code.Split('-').FirstOrDefault() equals s.Code                       
           select new { i, s };
```

but this is not working...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = from i in tableB
            from s in tableA 
            where i.Code.StartsWith(s.Code)
            select new { i, s };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
var query = TableA.Join(TableB, 
                   a => a.Code.Split('-').FirstOrDefault(),
                   b => b.SiteCode, 
                   (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b });
```

Comment: `Split` will not be translated into sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will help you. but make sure that first value can not be null.

```
var quer = from i in tableB
       join s in tableA on i.Code.Split('-')[0] equals s.Code                       
       select new { i, s };
```